# Show in OpenLayers style defined in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wfs, geoserver-styling

I have a WFS layer working correctly.
I configured the style in the GeoServer, but I am not able to fetch this style already defined in the GeoServer to show in OpenLayers.

On the GeoServer, the style is named

> style_layer1

How can I do this?

```js
var layer1 = new ol.layer.Vector({
    title: 'Layer 1',
    visible: false,
    zIndex: abrangencia,
    style: style_cadastro_lote,
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        url: function (extent) {
            return urlGeoserver + 'wfs?service=WFS&' +
                'version=' + versionGeoserver + '&request=GetFeature&typename=geo:LAYER1&' +
                'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:4326&' +
                'all=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:4326';

        },
        strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
    })
});
```

[EDIT]

Edit

```
var geojsonSource = new ol.source.Vector({
   format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    url: function(extent) {
       return urlGeoserver + 'wfs?service=WFS&' +
            'version=' + versionGeoserver + '&request=GetFeature&' +
            'typename=nome_da_camada&outputFormat=application/json&' +
            'srsname=EPSG:4326&' +
            'all=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:4326' +
           '&sld_url='+urlGeoserver +'/arquivo.sld';
},
 strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
});

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: geojsonSource
});

ol.format.SLD().readUrl(+urlGeoserver +'/arquivo.sld', function(sld) {
  var style = 
   ol.xml.getAllTextContent(sld.getElementsByTagName('CssParameter')[0]);
  vectorLayer.setStyle(style);
});
```

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/nieuwlandgeo/sldreader

Comment: @TomazicM, Thanks, I changed the code with an example I found, however, it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

OpenLayers cannot use SLD styling out of the box. You can use [GeoStyler](https://geostyler.org/) to convert SLD to OpenLayers style.

If you want to see the styled features, you can simply the use the WMS service from GeoServer. Indeed, you can use both WMS and WFS together in the same map. WMS could be used to displayed the styled features, whereas you can use the WFS to access the raw data.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into GeoStyler